# ORA-00379 no free buffers

Tags: oracle, backup

I'm trying to do `collection_manager` in OVPI but I'm getting db error

> ORA-00379 no free buffers available in buffer pool default for block
>   size 32k
>   oracle 10.2

Thanks for any help in advance

Comment: You could tell us what version of Oracle you are using and what DB_BLOCK_BUFFERS is set to. That would help.

Answer (score 2):

This is happening because your default database block size is set to something other than 32k, and as a result there's no 32k cache buffers available.

To fix this, add:

```
#change 1024M to the desired amount of cache
db_32k_cache_size=1024M
```

... to the init.ora for your database instance & then restart the database.

You may also be able to change this without restarting (as sysdba from sqlplus):

```
ALTER SYSTEM SET DB_32K_CACHE_SIZE=1024M;
```